# Netbeans uses wrong encoding on properties-files in maven project (utf-8)

Tags: netbeans, maven, character-encoding

I'm developing a webapp on linux using Netbeans 7 and maven. The pom files are opened in Netbeans. sourceEnocding in the poms are set to UTF8, still netbeans garbles the strings in the properties files, especially those for Norwegian, using a different codepage for those files. All I've found on the net says that any encoding settings in the pom-files will overrule native netbeans settings. Are there any special settings for properties-files that should be set in the poms?

```
<properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <configuration>
     <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This is the mother-pom and the problem occurs in a subproject. The resource-setting should be inherited?

Answer (score 0):

If your property files are in the `src/main/resource` folder, then you could be a victim of [this](http://johnnywey.wordpress.com/2009/11/04/careful-with-your-binary-resources/). See this [too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723598/java-io-ioexception-not-in-gzip-format-with-class-getresourceasstream). I thought my issue was with my encoding, but it was not.